# Redshift CPU utilisation is 100 percent most of the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a 96 Vcpu Redshift ra3.4xlarge 8 node cluster, Most of the times the CPU utilisation is 100 percent , It was a dc2.large 3 node cluster before , that was also always 100 percent that's why we increased it to ra3. We are doing most of our computes on Redshift but the data is not that much! I read somewhere Doesn't matter how much compute you increase unless its significantly , there will only be a slight improvement in the Computation. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doing most of our computes on Redshift"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that we run and do all the transformation of our SQL on redshift Cluster

Comment: Have you spent time optimizing your SQL transformations? It could be considerably cheaper to spend some time improving query performance than using a larger Redshift cluster.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah we are doing that but it still easily goes to 100 percent

Answer (score 2):

I can give it a shot.  Having 100% CPU for long stretches of time is generally not a good (optimal) thing in Redshift.  You see Redshift is made for performing analytics on massive amounts of structured data.  To do this it utilizes several resources - disks/disk IO bandwidth, memory, CPU, and network bandwidth.  If you workload is well matched to Redshift your utilization of all these things will average around 60%.  Sometimes CPU bound, sometimes memory bound, sometimes network bandwidth bound, etc.  Lots of data being read means disk IO bandwidth is at a premium, lots of redistribution of data means network IO bandwidth is constraining.  If you are using all these factors above 50% capacity you are getting what you paid for.  Once any of these factors gets to 100% there is a significant drop-off of performance as working around the oversubscribed item steals performance.

Now you are in a situation where you are see 100% for a significant portion of the operating time, right?  This means you have all these other attributes you have paid for but are not using AND inefficiencies are being realized to manage through this (though of all the factors, high CPU has the lease overhead).  The big question is why.

There are a few possibilities but the most likely, in my experience, is inefficiently queries.  An example might be the best way to explain this.  I've seen queries that are intended to find all the combinations of certain factors from several tables.  So they cross join these tables but this produces lots of repeats so they add DISTINCT, problem solved.  But this still creates all the duplicates and then reduces the set down.  All the work is being done and most of the results thrown away.  However, if they pared down the factors in the tables first, then cross joined them, the total work will be significantly lower.  This example will do exactly what you are seeing, high CPU as it spins making repeat combinations and then throwing most of them away.

If you have many of this type of "fat in the middle" query where lots of extra data is made and immediately reduced, you won't get a lot of benefit for adding CPU resources.  Things will get 2X faster with 2X the cluster size but you are buying 2X of all these other resources that aren't helping you.  You would expect that buying 2X CPU and 2X memory and 2X disk IO etc. would give you much more than a 2X improvement.  Being constrained on 1 thing make scaling costly.  Also, you are unlikely to see the CPU utilization come down as your queries just "spin the tires" of the CPU.  More CPUs will just mean you can run more queries resulting in the spinning more tires.

Now the above is just my #1 guess based on my consulting experience.  It could be that your workload just isn't right for Redshift.  I've seen people try to put many small database problems into Redshift thinking that it's powerful so it must be good at this too.  They turn up the slot count to try to pump more work into Redshift but just create more issues.  Or I've seem people try to run transactional workloads. Or ...  If you have the wrong tool for the job it may not work well.  One 6 ton dump truck isn't the same thing as 50 motorcycle delivery team - each has their purpose but they aren't interchangeable.

Another possibility is that you have a very unusual workload but Redshift is still the best tool for the job.  You don't need all the strengths of Redshift but this is ok, you are getting the job done at an appropriate cost.  If this case 100% CPU is just how your workload uses Redshift.  It's not a problem, just reality.  Now I doubt this is the case, but it is possible.  I'd want to be sure I'm getting all the value from the money I'm spending before assuming everything is ok.

Comment: I understand your points and get the whole idea of what you are expaling. Does that mean that using Distribution style ALL can help us reduce the disk IO as we don't have a problem with the Disk space. The maximum we can do is make our queries more efficient or re write them. But I think The disk space will still be a constraint. Disk space is not a problem as we have 760 GB of disk space available which is close to being utilised only 1 percent so clearly Disk is not an issue. I was thinking if we can move to EMR and have a little better approach in spark ?

Comment: As spark can take of lot of computation of the Redshift Cluster at the moment which will definitely help us to reduce the computation

Comment: DISTSTYLE ALL won't reduce your disk IO but can reduce network IO which can, at times, be more valuable.  Just need to do it wisely as it can make performance worse in some situations.  Small tables can actually take up less space is DISTSTYLE ALL.

Comment: EMR may be a better options for what you are doing, I just don't know your biz.  Map reduce was invented because there are real data problems that just don't run well (or at all) on a traditional databases.  However, this does not mean that EMR runs everything better.  IMO traditional databases are faster, cheaper, more efficient most of the time.  Let me tell you a story ...

Comment: A few years back I had a client that had a Redshift query that was taking 90 minutes to complete so they ported it to EMR, increased the spend-rate per hour by 4X (compared to Redshift) and got the run time down to 45 minutes.  Still not even close to fast enough.  They asked me to take a look at it and I rewrote the original query and it ran in 17 seconds on the original Redshift cluster.  The moral of this story is that computer systems only run what you tell them to.

Comment: I can't agree more to your last statement. But the problem with our firm is that all the transformations are run on Redshift and looker so basically there is no other processing layer. Thats Why I was thinking to take few things completely off grid where I can run in spark with better code writing style. IMO redshift is not made for heavy transformations it mostly for the simple Queries and data warehousing.

Comment: Also it would be cool if you can throw some light on what's disk IO vs Network IO. How do they differ completely ?

Comment: I have a 768 TB of Disk space with me , I have a table which is 150 GB , Do you think DistStyle ALL can help us to make it more faster . DistStyle ALL can make the table size to max of 900 GB based on 6 nodes cluster(Correct me if wrong : 150 * 6 nodes = 900 GB). SO disk Space isn't really a problem here

Comment: I'll have to disagree on "Redshift is not made for heavy transformations" point.  It isn't made to do everything and Big Data transformations do need to be written with data management in mind.  The optimal algorithm "style" for Redshift and EMR are different and your mileage may vary.

Comment: So Redshift is a cluster (just like EMR) where the nodes are linked together by ethernet cables.  These connections are high bandwidth but are still TCP/IP network connections with all the stack overhead and bandwidth constraints this brings.  Disk connections are SCSI connections (or similar) that directly connect the computer to the disks.  These disks are "local" to the computer and have higher bandwidth than network connections.  Based on the numbers you are giving I believe that you are on RA3 nodes which makes this a bit more confusing.

Comment: AWS doesn't publish disk sizes for RA3 nodes, just the addressable space.  Since these nodes use S3 to store the data and only keep "hot" data on the local disks they don't think you need to know this.  I'd guess that you are on ra3.4xlarge nodes which will have around 1TB of SSD disks per node (my estimate).  If I'm right this means that you have around 6TB of "hot data" space in your cluster.  The network interface on the node also provides connection to S3 and the "cold data" stored there.

Comment: So each node has some number of CPUs, some amount of memory, a network interface for connecting to the other nodes of the cluster & S3, and a disk interface for reading and writing data to disk.  Disk IO bandwidth and Network bandwidth are independent (for the most part) and each can be oversubscribed and limit performance.  On your RA3 cluster when you first run a query the data needs to be loaded from S3 and it will be saved to local disk for the next time it is needed.  This uses network bandwidth to bring in the data from S3 and disk bandwidth to store it on disk.

Comment: I don't think you have 768TB of disk space on your cluster.  This is the addressable data size for the cluster but your actual disk size is much smaller.  I'd need a lot more information about your workload to understand if DISTSTYLE ALL will be of benefit for your performance.   Since you say you are CPU limited in your workload and DISTSTYLE ALL generally helps with network bandwidth concerns, it seems like this would be of little value to you.

Comment: Can you drop an EXPLAIN plan for one of your more time / CPU consuming queries into the question?  I'm operating from very little data and a lot of assumptions.  Seeing a plan could help ground this conversation.